# select count(distinct) where col not like ('%d1,%d2,...')

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select 
    count(distinct [PROV_CT]) 
from 
    [HRecent] 
where 
    [PROV_CT] not like  ('%P125, %P961, %P160, %P960, %P220, %P004')
```

Can I write a query like this? Actually it is showing outputs which is different from the query output.

```
select  
    count(distinct [PROV_CT])
from
    [HRecent]
where 
    [PROV_CT] not like '%P125' and
    [PROV_CT] not like '%P220' and
    [PROV_CT] not like '%P960' and
    [PROV_CT] not like '%P004' and
    [PROV_CT] not like '%P961' and
    [PROV_CT] not like '%P160'
```

Can anyone help me out please? I want to write an optimised query.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: 1) Syntax reminds me of sqlserver, is it? 
2) I will bet you have Very Few rows where PROV_CTRCT fails the first pattern.
 Does the first query show the same output as this?
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PROV_CTRCT) FROM KMARTS.DBO.HUMANARECENT
3) Your 2nd query looks more like what you're trying w/the single LIKE in 1st query, except it yield a smaller cnt because rows are excluded.
Can you say more about the HUMANARECENT table (any indexes?), and what your values are like in PROV_CTRCT column:
 e.g. any nulls? shortest length? longest length? do the all end with smth like PCP999?

Comment: The first query's like pattern is likely not to match any record, so the second query is probably what you want. But what is the problem with the latter? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write the query using a single string literal like in:

```
[PROV_CT] not like  ('%P125, %P961, %P160, %P960, %P220, %P004')
```

This predicate doesn't look for *separate* values like `'%P125'`, `'%P961'` etc.

If you have a *very big list* of values against which `NOT LIKE` operation is to be performed, then it might be simpler to do it like this:

```
select  
    count(distinct [PROV_CT])
from
    [HRecent]
cross apply (
  select count(*)
  from (values ('%P125'), ('%P961'), 
               ('%P160'), ('%P960'), 
               ('%P220'), ('%P004') ) AS t(v)
  where [PROV_CT] LIKE t.v) AS x(cnt)
where x.cnt = 0
```

Using [**`VALUES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) Table Value Constructor you create an in-line table containing all the values against which `[PROV_CTRCT]` column is to be compared. Then query this table using a *single* `LIKE` operation to find if there is a match or not.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8431/4)

Comment: tq sir :) I got it now.